# How to a pass variable to read multiple SSL Schema_registry urls from a text file in python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Unable to read multiple urls from text file for SSL Avro Producer

```
AvroProducer{'schema_registry.url': filename}
```

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python

Comment: Getting 404 for your url. Please make sure it's not a private repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AvroProducer / Consumer in Python doesn't support more than one url.

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/409

And the property itself needs to be a string of `host:port`, not a file

The workaround would be to make http requests yourself, and retry over a list of addresses, then get the one that works, or take a moment to deploy a load balancer within your network

Comment: if not loadbalancer,do we have any other workaround as i would have to write multiple scripts for each dev, qa,sit environments as they have different schema_registry?

Comment: Why multiple scripts? You can make a single module that loops over a list of addresses, then import that for each environment